# Metalanguage on mathematics

Tags: terminology, education

I've heard that in the first class of my degree are teaching concepts like metalanguage. What does it mean. Could you give some examples? I've searched on google that metalanguage means representing another language called object language but I'm not able to create a relation with maths. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Supposedly the class itself will tell you what its concepts mean, right? It looks like you want to know the thing the course will teach you before taking it, but then why take it in the first place?